# Can I use var without initialization in c#?

Tags: c#

problem is defined in first comment in code,
what value should I set here so in try block I can set another value

```
var candidate_MNA = // what value should I set here so in try block I can set another value

try
{
     candidate_MNA = 
        (from c in db.ms_cadidate
         join h in db.ms_halqa
         on c.candidate_halqa_id equals h.halqa_id
         join p in db.ms_party
         on c.candidate_party_id equals p.party_id

         where h.halqa_id == SessionWrapper.user.user_halqa_id && c.candidate_type == "1"
         select new
         {
             candidate_id = c.candidate_id,
             halqa = h.halqa_no,
             fname = c.candidate_fname,
             party = p.party_name,
             partyFlag = p.party_flag,

         }).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: no you cannot use `var` without initialization

Comment: Of course you can't use `var` because at that time it's not clear what type `var` is a placeholder for. You have to declare it with the correct type. In case of an anonymous type you can't. Create a class `Candidate` or something like that

Comment: @john yeah, but think of a `try` block as an `if`... The assignment may never actually be reached, or there could be another assignment in the `finally` that would give `candidate_MNA` another type...

Comment: @Rafalon Oh no, I get that completely. You'd still have to initialize it as null. But the compiler could assume that it's the type of the first potential assignment in the code. I think this would be a terrible idea because it would potentially make code confusing to read (for the reason you specified). I'm simply saying that I can maybe understand why Mohammad thought this could be possible.

Comment: @john right, or even `object` or something alike, but no

Answer (score 6):

No you cannot do that because `var` resolves its type from the right hand side of the expression. What you can do is create `DTO` with the properties that you need out :

```
public class CandidateDTO
{   
  public int candidate_id {get;set;}
  public int halqa {get; set; }  
  .............
  ............
}
```

and then in your linq query use that type object :

```
 select new CandidateDTO
 {
    candidate_id = c.candidate_id,
    halqa = halqa_no,
    ..............
    ..............
 }
```

Now you use the variable outside the `try` like:

```
CandidateDTO candidate_MNA = null;
```

Answer (score -5):

It's possible, but messy:

```
var candidate_MNA = new
{
    candidate_id = default(int),
    halqa = default(int),
    fname = default(string),
    party = default(string),
    partyFlag = default(PartyFlag)
};
```

I'd suggest you are able to do better by changing where you define or use `candidate_MNA`.

Comment: well this initializes `candidate_MNA` doesn't it?

Comment: Please explain how that initialization isn't initializing the variable

Comment: @Rafalon maybe you could read the question, not just the title?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto maybe you too could read the question, not just the title?

Comment: @Rawling Then say *that* in an answer.  If you said, "no, it's not possible, but you could do something like this" then your solution would be a *bad* solution, and still worth downvoting (because it's *not* actually an appropriate solution to this problem), but not actually an *incorrect* solution, which is at least a step in the right direction.

Comment: @Servy Say *what* in an answer? "Read the question"?

Comment: @Rawling If you read past the first sentence of my comment, I provide an explicit quote of what you could have said.  I don't know what could be more clear than that.  But if you need me to repeat myself, no, you shouldn't edit your answer to say, "read the question".  It'd be better if you *actually read the question yourself* and provided a correct answer to it, instead of providing an incorrect answer to it.

Comment: @Servy Your comment "Say *that* in an answer" implies I followed up my answer with something that you believe should be in the answer itself, but I've not. I maintain that my answer is correct, and it is the comments/answers saying "it's impossible" that are incorrect. I'll also point out that I said "it's messy" and "you can do better by refactoring" but go ahead and ignore that too.

Comment: What Servy said, you should say "it's not possible without initialization, **but** you could do this...". Because this requires initialization, the title explicitly asks for no initialization

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto The first line of the question is *what value should I set here so in try block I can set another value*. He's asking for an value to set there!

Comment: @Rawling Once again, please read past the first sentence of my first comment.  While you could indeed imply several different things from the first sentence, alone, if you read the rest, I further clarify what I was suggesting you include.  I added this further clarification specifically because I knew it was ambiguous.  But no,  your answer is not correct.  You claim that it's possible to use `var` with an uninitialized variable, and demonstrated this by showing an example of using var...with an initialized variable, rather than an uninitialized variable.

Comment: @Servy I don't claim to demonstrate how to do it without initializing. I claim to demonstrate "what value should I set here so in try block I can set another value" which is what the *question* asks. Twice.

Comment: Then at best your answer is ambiguous in indicating which of the two different questions you're answering.

Comment: @Servy Best two out of three? (loving it... going from "It'd be better if you *actually read the question yourself*" to "... oh, maybe you should have clarified that you were answering the question")